# Using CData Sync to migrate data from SQL Server to MariaDB?

Tags: sql-server, mariadb

I am trying to migrate a table called `table1` in SQL Server with the following details:

| username | account_name | description | change_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| nvarchar(255) | nvarchar(255) | nvarchar(255) | date |
| primary_key |  |  |  |

I am using CData to migrate this table to my MariaDB database. If anyone here is familiar with CData, the command I am using to migrate the table is `REPLICATE [dbo].[table1]`. When I run the code in CData, I am getting an error stating: `BLOB/TEXT column 'username' used in key specification without key length (1170)`. I don't understand this error because I do not have a BLOB/TEXT column in my table anywhere. When migrating the data to MariaDB, `nvarchar` should convert to `varchar` (which it has done for my other tables so not sure why this is causing an issue here). Is it because it's the primary key? I can't delete the PK on this table, I need it there so I'm not sure how to fix this issue.